# Angular and Node js Twitter Login

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, twitter

I am trying to do twitter authentication with Angular and node js and its not working. I have this from angular:

```
   signInWithTwitter() {
     this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/twitter`, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe((results) => 
    {
     // The url is -> https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxx
      window.location.href = results["url"];
    }); 
  }
```

I am sending the window.location.href because i can't call any external links from angular and on node js i have:

```
var _requestSecret;

app.get("/twitter", (req, res) => {
   tw.login((err, tokenSecret, url) => {
    if (err) {
    // Handle the error your way
    }

   // Save the OAuth token secret for use in your /twitter/callback route
   _requestSecret = tokenSecret;

   res.json({ url: url });


 });
});
```

and the callback function on node js is:

```
app.get("/twitter/callback", (req, res) => { tw.callback({
      oauth_token: req.query.oauth_token,
      oauth_verifier: req.query.oauth_verifier,
    },
    _requestSecret,
    (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle the error your way
    }

    // Redirect to whatever route that can handle your new Twitter login user details!
    res.redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
  }
);
});
```

I have the user on the twitter/callback but i need a way to send the user to angular.

Comment: did you set  http://localhost:3000  as auth callback url in your twitter developer console project ?

Comment: Yes, the callback gets called with the user information, i just can’t send it back to Angular